# Newcomer Question

Tags: discussion, questions

I just thought I'd introduce myself to everyone on this site. My name is Suhayl, and I'm an aspiring poetry writer. Being a poetry writer, I, naturally have an infatuation with the English language, it's many intricacies, synonyms, and just the overall beauty of the language. Being that it is not my first language, I do at times struggle with the usage, be it written or spoken. I am hoping to learn much on this site, and hopefully acquire new skills along the way. I would sincerely appreciate anyone who after reading my posts, takes their time out to correct any errors, be they incorrect wording, punctuation etc.
Regards, Suhayl

P.s I take it I can't discuss poetry on here?

Comment: Welcome friend.

Comment: Thank you. I'm happy to be here

Comment: You could start by learning that what you call a "poetry writer" already has a name in English.

Comment: I take it you mean poet? Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, unless your intention was to get a job at a greeting-card company.

Comment: Maybe it is. Anyway, thank you for your reply

Comment: Welcome! I hope you find this site helpful. I would like to add that we don't proofread here, either. We can certainly edit, but it is usually done more for clarity than the poster's edification. In any case, there is ample opportunity to better your knowledge of English here, even for native speakers (like me.)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for informing me. I think I'm starting to understand the purpose of the site a little better.

Comment: Welcome Suhayl! I come here every day to learn new things, or be reminded of what I used to know but have forgotten! I've spent time on many SE sites, and am so impressed by the nice welcome you received, so I wanted to say thanks to you for introducing yourself, and to the others for being so sweet.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome, Suhayl.

I hope you find EL&U an enlightening place. There is certainly a wealth of knowledge relating to [synonyms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonyms), and not just synonyms, but thousands of [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests). When it comes to [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality) and [usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usage), we've got you covered.

While there is a [poetry](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poetry) section, we don't actually analyse poetry, per se. We do answer questions about the [meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning) of words, in a specific context, though.

Hopefully you've noticed that your question has moved from the main site, to our meta site (the background is grey, not off-cream), where people ask questions about the site itself.

You should definitely take the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.

It is important to note that Stack Exchange provide question and answer websites, not discussion forums.

So, you are quite right, there is no discussion of poetry on the main site. There *shouldn't be* any kind of discussion on the main site.

You might also be interested in two other Stack Exchange sites:

- [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com), a Q&A site for professional and aspiring writers
- [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Welcome again.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful reply

Comment: "grey, not off-cream" Not to split hairs- okay, that's a lie; I'm totally splitting hairs right now, but... This is kind of a blue-gray. A steel gray. And the other site isn't "off-cream". It's totally tan. Grayish-tan. I expect your signed letter of apology on my desk no later than eight sharp tomorrow morning.

Comment: @ParthianShot - colors may vary on different screens (does anyone have monitors anymore?).

Comment: @medica They shouldn't, though. They're [supposed to not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB). That having been said, I suppose it also depends on background color, personal bias, and whether or not you were amused by that scene in Red Dwarf where they repaint the hallway from "marine gray" to "battleship gray".

Comment: @ParthianShot - Now, I don't "see" how anyone can't get [a perfect score on this test](http://www.xrite.com/online-color-test-challenge). I did. But not everyone actually sees the same thing when they look at a color.

Comment: @medica That would easily take 30 minutes to complete. Too time-consuming!

Comment: @AndrewLeach Hmm. That might be because you're a man. Took me about 7 minutes (most women have better color vision than many men.)